# Elasticache in .net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, amazon-elasticache

Does elasticache supports the .net core 2.0? I am trying to implement elasticache in .net core webApi app but not sure how to configure it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  ServiceStack Radis nuget package
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Redis.Core/

Answer (score 1):

ElastiCache supports Redis and Memcached clients, so to implement it you could use a library such as [StackExchange Redis](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/) or [EnyimMemcachedCore](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/EnyimMemcachedCore)

Comment: Is it possible using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.Core ?

Comment: @BrijenPatel Yes